# Why is AFNetworking still using UIAlertView though Apple says its deprecated?

Tags: afnetworking-2

See UIAlertView + AFNetworking.m

Since I am using pod install, I do not want to change this every time.
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking still supports `UIAlertView` because AFNetworking 2 supports a minimum iOS target of iOS 6.

You can safely ignore the deprecation warnings if you're not using `UIAlertView` in your app (or suppress them if they're really bothering you).

You could also open a pull request for UIKit+AFNetworking that switches over to `UIAlertController` when available.